# How to expose an object from a VanillaJS library built with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm developing a Vanilla JS library. This library will have to expose an object, let's call it `sdk`: this object will contain all the library methods, so a potential user can do

```
<script src="thelibrary.js"></script>
<script>
   sdk.myFunction();
</script>
```

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry:
    ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'my-sdk.js',
    library: 'my-sdk-function',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This is my `index.js`

```
const myFunction = () => { 
   console.log('hello'); 
}
const sdk = { myFunction };
```

How can I achieve my objective?

I have an `index.html` file that I'm serving via a python SimpleHTTPServer:

```
<body>
  <script src="http://localhost:5000/dist/my-sdk.js"></script>
</body>
```

But I'm not able to access the `sdk` object... what is my mistake?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can assign your sdk to the global window. You would then have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short anwser** - you are looking for:

```
output: {                                                                                                                                                                          
  library: {                                                                                                                                                                       
    type: "window",                                                                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                                                               
},
```

with `webpack.config.js` containing that, my `sdk` object is available on `window` - as you stated in your question.

**Long answer** - that resembles a lot how js libraries were written many years ago. It still can be a valid use case now but can put away people from modern projects away from your library. I would aim for building at least 2 files:

1. standard output, to be imported via wepback or by another modern tool
2. global scope polluting one, as you stated in your question

The repo I was experimenting with is here:
https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-sdk

And an example of how it's working is here:
https://marcin-wosinek.github.io/webpack-sdk/